# How do I make a pair with a list of different number of elements?

Tags: python

I would like to pair a + d , c + e, and b+x.
but I don't know how to do it.

I thought I could do it using zip_longest, but
It did not work.

```
combine_list = zip_longest(list1, list2)
```

I am scraping a BBS and getting information across multiple pages.

---

Thread title : Shop A

Thread URL : https://thread1, thread2

Page1 comment : blah blah blah

Page2 comment : blah blah blah

---

Thread title : Shop B

Thread URL : https://thread1

Page1 comment: blah blah blah

---

Thread title : Shop C

Thread URL : https://thread1, thread2

Page1 comment : blah blah blah

Page2 comment : blah blah blah

---

list1 = ['ShopA', 'thread_url', 'Page1 comment'] , ['ShopB', 'thread_url', 'Page1 comment'], ['ShopC', 'thread_url', 'Page1 comment']

list2 = ['ShopA', 'thread_url', 'Page2 comment'] , ['ShopC', 'thread_url', 'Page1 comment']

I have a situation like this, and I want to combine the comments of Page1 and Page2 of Shop A into one comment.
Shop B wants to get the comments as Shop B. Shop C wants to combine the comments of Page1 and Page2.

What is the best way to do this?

Waiting for help.

**Code**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pymongo
import re
import time
import itertools



def browse_header():
    headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Mac OS X x86_64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0"}

    return headers


def domain():
    domain = 'https://bakusai.com'

    return domain


def bbs_url_out():

    thread_list = []

    with open('./thread_url.csv', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for urls in f:
            thread_list.append(urls.strip())

    return thread_list


def thread_requests_parse():
    headers = browse_header()
    url_list = bbs_url_out()

    thread_url_lists = []

    for thread_url in url_list:
        time.sleep(1)
        try:
            r = requests.get(thread_url, headers=headers)
            thread_url_lists.append(thread_url)

        except Exception as ex:
            print('Except:', ex)
            pass

    return thread_url_lists


def thread_article_parse(domain):

    thread_url_lists = thread_requests_parse()
    headers = browse_header()
    domain = domain
    shop_info_list_1 = []


    for thread_url in thread_url_lists:
        try:
            r = requests.get(thread_url, headers=headers)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
            htmls = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'article'})
            title1 = soup.find('div', {'id': 'title_thr'}).text


            shop_texts_1 = []
            for html in htmls:
                post = html.get_text()
                time_pat = r'\d\d:\d\d'
                posts = re.split(time_pat, post)
                time_post = re.search(time_pat, post)
                try:
                    seikei1_1 = str(posts[0]) + time_post.group() + '\n' + '<br><br><span style="font-size: 200%;"><b>' + str(posts[1]) + '\n' + '</span></b><br>[匿名さん]<br><br>'
                    seikei1_2 = re.sub('最新レス', '', seikei1_1)
                    seikei1_3 = seikei1_2.replace('[匿名さん]', '')
                    # print(seikei1_3)
                    shop_texts_1.append(seikei1_3)

                except Exception as ex:
                    print('Except:', ex)
                    pass

            thread_info_list = list([title1, thread_url, shop_texts_1])
            shop_info_list_1.append(thread_info_list)
            print(shop_info_list_1)

        except Exception as ex:
            print('Except:', ex)
            pass

    def next_page_url_parse():
        thread_url_lists = thread_requests_parse()
        next_url_lists = []

        for thread_url in thread_url_lists:
            try:
                r = requests.get(thread_url, headers=headers)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

                nexts = soup.find('div', {'class': 'paging'}).find('span', {'class': 'paging_nextlink'}).find('a')
                b = nexts.get('href')
                next_url = domain + b
                print('[thread_parse] : next_url', f'{next_url}')
                next_url_lists.append(next_url)

            except Exception as ex:
                print('Except:', ex)
                pass

        return next_url_lists


    def next_page_thread_parse():
        next_url_lists = next_page_url_parse()
        shop_info_list_next = []

        for next_url in next_url_lists:
            r2 = requests.get(next_url, headers=headers)
            soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r2.text, 'html.parser')
            html2s = soup2.find_all('div', {'class': 'article'})
            title2 = soup2.find('div', {'id': 'title_thr'}).text


            shop_texts2 = []
            for html2 in html2s:
                post2 = html2.get_text()
                time_pat = r'\d\d:\d\d'
                posts2 = re.split(time_pat, post2)
                time_post = re.search(time_pat, post2)

                try:
                    seikei2_1 = str(posts2[0]) + time_post.group() + '\n' + '<br><br><span style="font-size: 200%;"><b>' + str(posts2[1]) + '\n' + '</span></b><br>[匿名さん]<br><br>'
                    seikei2_2 = re.sub('最新レス', '', seikei2_1)
                    seikei2_3 = seikei2_2.replace('[匿名さん]', '')
                    # print('[thread_parse]', seikei2_3)
                    shop_texts2.append(seikei2_3)
                except Exception as ex:
                    print('Except:', ex)
                    pass

            thread_info_list_next = list([title2, next_url, shop_texts2])
            shop_info_list_next.append(thread_info_list_next)
            print(shop_info_list_next)

            # write_text2 = '\n'.join(texts2)
            # print(write_text2)
        # with open('./thread.txt', mode='a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        #     f.write('\n\n' + write_text2 + '\n\n')

        return shop_info_list_next

    shop_info_list_next = next_page_thread_parse()


    shop_info_list_matome = list(itertools.zip_longest(shop_info_list_1, shop_info_list_next))


    # thread_info_list = list([title1, thread_url, shop_texts_1, shop_texts2])
    # print(thread_info_list)
    return shop_info_list_matome

def text_mix(shop_info_list_matome):

    shop_info_list_matome = shop_info_list_matome
    for shop_info_list in shop_info_list_matome:
        for texts in shop_info_list:
            print(texts, type(texts))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    browse_header()
    domain = domain()
    bbs_url_out()
    shop_info_list_matome = thread_article_parse(domain)
    text_mix(shop_info_list_matome)
```

Comment: This question would be easier to answer with a working code demonstration if you provided working Python statements (e.g. `list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']`) including what you want the final output to look like.

Comment: Did you really want c+e and b+x? That's matching the third element in list1 to the 2nd element in list2, not very intuitive... If so, can you spell out the logic to determine which element x gets paired with in general?

Comment: `x`? What is `x`?

Comment: I used 'x' to mean that it should have something in it, none, nan, whatever.

Comment: So list1 always has three elements and list2 always has 2 elements?

Comment: @KellyBundy Yes

Comment: I tried this code and could not make a pair
`combine_list = list(itertools.zip_longest(list1, list2, fillvalue=None))`

Comment: What does "could not make a pair" mean?  What did you get, and what were you hoping to get?  (Add that information to your original question, please.)

Comment: @Samwise ok, sec

Comment: It's not at all clear after your edit what your lists look like or what you want your final combined list to look like.  Please include some actual Python code as an example.  My best guess from reading your description (absent any information about how the data is structured) would be that you want to combine multiple keys within a dict, and this has nothing to do with lists or `zip` at all.  Or maybe these are just blobs of text, and the question is really about parsing them into useful data structures?

Comment: @Samwise I thought so and added the code. I should have done this from the beginning.

Comment: What does "but It did not work" mean? What output do you get? What do you want instead? See [mcve] for tips on making a code example. Your question has nothing to do with web scraping, so showing code with requests and beautifulsoup only adds noise that makes it harder for us to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think you want to do is build a dict keyed on the shop name (the first element of each sublist) so that you can combine all the info from different pages for a given shop.  Here's some example code:

```
page1 = [['ShopA', 'thread_url', 'Page1 comment'], ['ShopB', 'thread_url', 'Page1 comment'], ['ShopC', 'thread_url', 'Page1 comment']]
page2 = [['ShopA', 'thread_url', 'Page2 comment'], ['ShopC', 'thread_url', 'Page1 comment']]

shops = {}
for page in (page1, page2):
    for shop, thread_url, comment in page:
        shops.setdefault(shop, []).extend([thread_url, comment])

combined = [[k] + v for k, v in shops.items()]
print("\n".join(map(str, combined)))
# ['ShopA', 'thread_url', 'Page1 comment', 'thread_url', 'Page2 comment']
# ['ShopB', 'thread_url', 'Page1 comment'], 
# ['ShopC', 'thread_url', 'Page1 comment', 'thread_url', 'Page1 comment']
```

You'll probably need to modify this code for your purposes, since you didn't give an example of exactly *how* you wanted to combine the lists, but hopefully this is enough to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you. That is correct.
I have been working on this problem for about 12 hours and my head was dead.

I will try!